# Map is not working in android after submitting both sha-1 key

Tags: android, dictionary

Map is not working in release build after uploading sha-1 key debug and realse sha-1 key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have two google_maps_api.xml files, one in the app/src/debug/res/values folder and the other in the app/src/release/res/values folder, but only the debug one contains your API key.

Put you map_key in both files[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM0nK.png)

Comment: Yes. It's solution